# Android studio tem suporte a ndk?

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-studio

Vou começar desenvolvimento voltado para tv digital, e será 50% ndk.Android studio atende bem? ou é melhor eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir da [versão 1.3 do Android Studio](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio13preview1available), possui o total suporte para o NDK, incluindo um debug nativo. O plugin é baseado no [JetBrains CLion platform](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/).

[image: Android Studio com NDK]

Fonte:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-m-developer-preview-tools.html

Answer (score 1):

Use o `Android Studio` ele tem suporte total ao `Android` e é passivel da utilização dos plugins da jetbrains, o Google não fornece mais suporte ao `ADT` (plugin do eclipse para desenvolver `Android`), logo o `ADT` tende a não suportar as novas APIs do `Android` (que atualmente esta na revisão 22).

Nota sobre ADT:

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

Fonte: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html